# Unity3d - Not showing web view when i take screen shot

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, webview, screenshot

I have an issue,
When  i take screen shot in unity,  only webview in unity is not showing in  the screen shot , but the webview,UI    display is normal on device  ,so i dont understand why  photo only UI display ,webview is not showing on the screen shot .